# Django INNER JOIN using foreign key with WHERE clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

So I have a db structure where users are following other users. In the inbuilt User model I have fields like 'first_name', 'username' etc... The Friendship model is as follows:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    tail_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='follower')   #The one who sent the friend request
    head_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='followed')
```

Some of the users don't have first_name at given moment and will be updated later. Now for a specific user (say actor) I want to get all his friends who have a first_name. Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM friendship JOIN user ON friendship.head_user_id=user.id WHERE user.first_name != ''
```

How can I achieve this in Django ORM, if possible without using subquery.

The sql query I provided might be wrong, it's just to convey what i'm trying to express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) the empty first_name values:

```
Friendship.objects.exclude(head_user__first_name='')
```

Note that if the `first_name` is `NULL` (not an empty string), you would need to use [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull):

```
Friendship.objects.exclude(head_user__first_name__isnull=True)
```

And, yeah, you can chain excludes if you do want to exclude both `NULL` and empty values:

```
Friendship.objects.exclude(head_user__first_name__isnull=True) \
                  .exclude(head_user__first_name='')
```